# Error when initializing mongo database in a Meteor app running on Nitrous.io

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nitrousio

I have set up my Meteor dev environment on Nitrous.io according to the instructions provided (using Autoparts). Everything was running smoothly until I did a "meteor reset" to delete the data in the mongo db. Since then I haven't been able to restart my app as mongo seems to crash on startup.

Any ideas?

```
Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

events.js:72                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
              ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    at /home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/tools/09b63f1ed5/tools/mongo_runner.js:285:36                                                                                                                                                                                  
    at /home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/admin.js:257:31                                                                                                                                        
    at /home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1079:18                                                                                                                                          
    at /home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1670:9                                                                                                                                           
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:382:41)                                                                                                   
    at /home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:472:18                                                                                                                            
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)                                                                                                   
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:430:20)                                                                                                         
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/0.7.0.1/packages/mongo-livedata/133ed3e7a3/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:191:13)
```

Comment: Could you try reinstalling Meteor? You can run `parts uninstall meteor` followed by `parts install meteor` for a complete re-install.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it by uninstalling dbmongo autopart. Meteor is running is own instance of mongodb (minimongo) and it seems that there is a issue starting it when you have dbmongo autopart installed.

Comment: I don't have a mongodb autopart installed. I only have the Meteor part.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself without me changing anything. I was able to start the Meteor server today. It would be interesting to find out why and when this happens though.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue persists. Meteor crashes every once in a while for some reason. I guess I will stick to my Ubuntu VMware box for development.

Answer (score 0):

> I faced the same problem and I fixed it by uninstalling dbmongo autopart.

Uninstalling mongodb autopart and restarting the box worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at your disk Space. If quota is exceeded the app will crash with the same error you encounter.

run this : du /home -h --max-depth=1
and then clean your space ;-)

Answer (score -1):

May this could help.
Find the process typing this in the console:
 lsof -i tcp:$PORT
Then kill the process like this:
 kill -9 PID

May some process could be causing troubles. At less that was something that happend to me.
This is something that I found working with MEAN.